# How do i use a variable value as the id of an HTML element on a gsp page?

Tags: html, grails, groovy, gsp

I am trying to dynamically set the id values of some elements on a gsp page. The values are passed to the page from the controller when I render it. 
However, when I look at the source code, the value of the id is not set.

I am trying to do the following:

```
<g:each in="${listBenefits}" var="benefit" status="i">
    <div class="card"  id="${benefit.getId()}">
...
</g:each>
```

but the value is not inserted into the id.

I can, however, do the following:

```
<h1>${benefit.getId()}</h1>
```

And the value is displayed.

I have tried to set the value to a variable before using it like this

```
<g:set var="idaccordion" value="${benefit.getId()}" />
<div class="card"  id="${idaccordion}">
```

and does not work either.

I am expecting to get something like this:

```
<div class="card"  id="desired_id">
```

and instead I get something like this

```
<div class="card"  id="">
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds strange. It should work. Could you put together h1 and div into one `each` and show code and result? Without any other tags ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to find any mistakes in your work. I suggest you try the following snippet in the same view (i.e. gsp page) and see how it is rendered.

```
<g:each in="${1..3}" var="rn">
    <div id="${rn}">Test ${rn}</div>
</g:each>
```

If the code works properly, I reckon you need to revise `benifit.getId()` method. You're able to use `benefit.id` to see whether it gives any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was the benefit.getId() method. I was not handling correctly one of the cases and it was returning null, thus causing this to fail.